# Fatal error: Class 'Object' not found C:\xampp\htdocs\<app folder>\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php on line 58

Tags: cakephp, xampp

I know this a very generic question, however I am frustrated with it.I am pretty new with implementing php project so please bear with me. 
I recently got a new PC for a client and need to configure PHP app onto it. I installed XAMPP and apache,mysql is started. 
When I open `localhost` on browser it opens dashboard for `Welcome to XAMPP for windows 7.2.12.` 
I created a new php file with `<?php phpinfo();?>` and it shows me PHP's page. So now I think all are set. 
However , now I copied file which was hosted online and save it in htdocs folder it gives
`localhost is unable to handle this request 
http error 500`
We have resolved this issue by giving Full Control to tmp folder and setting up database connection by changing configure::write('debug',2); changed value from 0 to 2. 
Now, we are getting error `Fatal error: Class 'Object' not found C:\xampp\htdocs\<app folder>\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php on line 58`
on Line 58 of Controller.php file, I have 
`class Controller extends Object implements CakeEventListener{`

So, I am not confident in touching config files . So please advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check PHP version of the live server from where you are downloading CakePHP files.

I guess its PHP version compatibility issue. If it version compatibility issue then please remove XAMPP from your local PC and install same PHP version which is installed on your live server (i.e.  PHP5.6 or PHP7.0 or PHP7.1).

IF still facing issues then please share the CakePHP Version you are trying to run on the local machine.

Comment: online server has `PHP 5.6.36` and cake version is `Cake 2.9'

Comment: @mark Are you still facing the issue or working fine ?

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is [not a valid class name since PHP/7.2](https://3v4l.org/5JMSV), as listed in [Backward incompatible changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.object-reserved-word):

> ## `object` for class names
>
> The `object` name was previously soft-reserved in PHP 7.0. This is now
>   hard-reserved, prohibiting it from being used as a class, trait, or
>   interface name.

Chances are that you're running a CakePHP version that's [older than 2.9.0](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-9-migration-guide.html):

> ### Deprecations
>
> The Object class has been deprecated and renamed to CakeObject due to object becoming a reserved keyword in one of the next PHP7 minors
>   (see
>   [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reserve_even_more_types_in_php_7)).

You need to either upgrade CakePHP or downgrade PHP.